# Unexpected Token Where

Tags: dynamic-soql

```
  for(AggregateResult hier:hierarchy) {
    fld1.add((String)hier.get(Field1));
    fld2.add((String)hier.get(Field2));
    fld3.add((String)hier.get(Field3));
           }

        string Soqlstr2='Select Name FROM' + val + ' WHERE ' + Field1 + ' IN :\'' + fld1 + '\' AND ' +
            Field2 + ' IN :\'' + fld2 + '\' AND ' +
            Field3 + ' IN :\'' + fld3 + '\' AND ' +'\'';
```

I am getting an error :

> Unexpected Token Where .

Answer (score 3):

Your query is missing a space after `FROM`. The resulting query would look like

```
SELECT Name FROMAccount WHERE ...
```

This is a very easy error to make, and is why I always recommend using `String.format()` to build Dynamic SOQL queries, as I mentioned on one of your previous questions.

You are also using Apex binding incorrectly. An Apex bind takes the form `:VARIABLE`, as in `WHERE My_Field__c IN :collectionOfValues`. Your query adds the literal string value of the variable after the binding colon, which will produce confusing errors at run time.

I strongly recommend that you take the time to read through the *entirety* of Salesforce's [SOSL and SOQL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm). Your questions indicate that you are working on a project involving a lot of complex querying. You **need** to establish a foundation in how these query languages work in order to do so effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a dynamic query via string concatenation there is always a scope for such error. A better way to do this will be to use String.format which gives you templated string that you can replace. It makes your query more readable.

```
String Soqlstr2='SELECT Name FROM {0} WHERE {1} = :{2} AND  {3} = :{4} ';

String SOQLqueryFinal = String.format(Soqlstr2, new List<String>{
                            'ID','accountIDList','Name','accountNameList'
                        });
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_format